# How do I set executable permissions on a removable drive?

Tags: gnome, permissions, usb-drive, udev

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and using a usb drive but I'm finding that I can't chmod any programs on the drive to +x. It is being auto-mounted by Gnome (using udev, I think?) so I imagine the problem is a mount option but I can't seem to find a way to modify the default mount options any where. There are no entries in fstab.
Anybody encounter this problem?

Comment: If it's vfat/ntfs, you can set the default permissions with the dmask/fmask mount options **mount -o umask=xxx** depending on what rights you want, **umask=0** will give all rights..

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to find out how to modify these options for when Gnome automounts an inserted device. I have it mounted manually to another location from an entry in /etc/fstab, so this will work for the time being, it's a bit inconvenient though.

Comment: No EASY way in 2019??  No plug-and-play  to do that with UBUNTU 18 LTS??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess your usb drive is formatted with VFAT/FAT32.  This file format does not support execute permissions which is why *chmod +x* fails.

[Edit]
Ok, had a bit of a play and search on the net.  Lots of 'solutions' suggest that you should change */etc/fstab*.  This just seems clunky to me, what do you do? change *fstab* every time you encounter a new usb flash drive???

My solution:

$ *sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/90-usb-disks.rules*

Add the lines:

```
# UDEV Rules to change the permission of USB disks
#

KERNEL=="sd*[0-9]", ATTR{removable}=="1", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", MODE="0022"
```

$ *sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart*

Then try inserting a usb drive.  There is probably an attribute that you can check for to ensure it's a FAT formatted drive if you wanted to be more specific.

Comment: It seems not, I added an entry to /etc/fstab with the options I require and I'll just have to mount it manually every time I insert it until I can figure out how to modify the default mount options.

Comment: Ah,this is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find the right file. Worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your solution but it is not working for me. Can you take a look at my question? http://askubuntu.com/q/138878/25305 Thanks in advance

Comment: How can I make it only for vfat systems?

Comment: So does the drive have to be a FAT formatted drive?

Comment: @Philip, that is AFAIK because Ubuntu switched to systemd.