# usb devices unacessible

Tags: usb, permissions, guest-session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Changing file permissions on USB external hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138878/changing-file-permissions-on-usb-external-hard-drive)

I have a funny thing happening with my USB devices. They are detected and show up as they should but I cannot write to them, I can read the files in them.

[image: Read only]

[image: Cannot change option]

I cannot change the Group folder access. It keeps reverting to none when I try change it.

However when I start a guest session and copy a screen shot to the USB I can, but cannot in my regular administration session. Why cannot I change the option and why does it behave properly in a guest session but not normally? Anyone know how to help me out here?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit.

Comment: Please take a look at [Subv3rsion's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/138884/18887) on [Changing file permissions on USB external Hard-Drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138878/changing-file-permissions-on-usb-external-hard-drive)

Comment: I think this is a different issue.  I seem to remember seeing this problem before, but I believe it is a distinct problem from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, I have what seems to be the same problem on my flash drive.  Except I use the terminal commands [`cp`, `rm`, etc], and it says permission denied.  However when I become root it works.

But for now, try this in a terminal:

`$ gksu nautilus`

Then try using **that** window to copy files.  I believe you will find it does, because it's using root permissions.  Be careful with that window, because you can remove system files, so I do not recommend using Nautilus as root normally, but in this case you might need to until you figure out how to fix the flash drive.

I am thinking about formatting my flash drive to see if it fixes the root-only permissions.

Comment: This is not a purely USB stick problem. it is affecting my Kindle as well, I cannot add/remove from it with Calibre.