# Can't delete folder even with all permission and sudo

Tags: command-line, permissions, filesystem, directory, delete

I have all the necessary permission to delete the folder

```
ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4096 Oct 15 16:20 WindowsApps
```

However on trying to delete the folder

```
sudo rm -r -f WindowsApps
```

```
rm: cannot remove 'WindowsApps/Microsoft.GamingApp_2008.1001.11.0_neutral_split.scale-125_8wekyb3d8bbwe/Assets': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove 'WindowsApps/Microsoft.GamingApp_2008.1001.11.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe/AppxMetadata/AppxBundleManifest.xml': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'WindowsApps/Microsoft.GamingApp_2008.1001.11.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/AppxMetadata/CodeIntegrity.cat': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'WindowsApps/Microsoft.GamingApp_2008.1001.11.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/Assets/JumpList': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove 'WindowsApps/Microsoft.GamingApp_2008.1001.11.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/Bundle/assets/src/windows/app/assets': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove 'WindowsApps/Microsoft.GamingApp_2008.1001.11.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/Bundle/index.bundle': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'WindowsApps/Microsoft.GamingApp_2008.1001.11.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/microsoft.system.package.metadata': Directory not empty
```

Even when i try deleting individual files by cd into the folder

```
sudo rm -r AppxBundleManifest.xml
rm: cannot remove 'AppxBundleManifest.xml': No such file or directory
```

The folder is a remnant of Windows Xbox game pass and its corresponding windows installation has been deleted.I have also tried deleting from a new windows installation.This folder is located on my external hdd where the other folders are not effected by this behavior.

ls -l for a file in the folder

```
-rwxrwxrwx 2 user user 12502 Aug 30 01:26 AppxBundleManifest.xml
```

Comment: Welcome, the drive we assume is NTFS. Perform disk check and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: you are missing info: please also provide `ls -l` for the file you get this error on. and please tell us the mount options if any,

Comment: Updated with the file permissions , the hdd is NTFS formatted mounted on ‘/media/user/67CBAF013605A3AF’

Comment: Did you tried u to go in the archive of this folder, try to delete it in the archive. As an example: if the file test is in the archive /etc/local/test, then try to delete the folder in `cd /etc/local`. If it does not work I tried my best to help you.

Comment: Remotely related to (and definitely nod duplicate of) https://askubuntu.com/q/1130564/778232 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted this file following this [tutorial](https://thegeekpage.com/solved-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-the-container-windows-10-error/). You would need to boot into your windows system for this

From the tutorial:

Copy and paste the commands given below in the command prompt window and execute the commands one by one.

```
takeown /F X:\FULL_PATH_TO_FOLDER

takeown /F X:\FULL_PATH_TO_FOLDER /r /d y

icacls X:\FULL_PATH_TO_FOLDER /grant Administrators:F

icacls X:\FULL_PATH_TO_FOLDER /grant Administrators:F /t
```

I am still intrigued by how I couldn't delete a file even with Sudo and all permissions and whether this is a possible bug in Linux.