# 23.10 Cannot mount USB key

Tags: mount, ntfs, 23.10

I've just updated Ubuntu to 23.10 but I cannot mount my USB key anymore (NTFS).

Here is the end of dmesg :

```
$dmesg
[  217.932240] ntfs3: sda: It is recommened to use chkdsk.
[  217.939261] ntfs3: sda: volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set!
[  233.625404] ntfs3: sda: It is recommened to use chkdsk.
[  233.632438] ntfs3: sda: volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set!
[  245.269409] sda: detected capacity change from 30433280 to 0
[  250.759968] usb 7-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  260.864687] usb 7-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  260.900023] usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0918, bcdDevice= 3.10
[  260.900040] usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  260.900047] usb 7-2: Product: Disk 3.0
[  260.900054] usb 7-2: Manufacturer: USB
[  260.900059] usb 7-2: SerialNumber: 4357078231863886
[  260.901014] usb-storage 7-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  260.901645] scsi host0: usb-storage 7-2:1.0
[  261.918826] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB      Disk 3.0         0009 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  261.919446] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  261.920203] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 30433280 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.5 GiB)
[  261.920630] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  261.920639] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[  261.921027] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  261.925393]  sda:
[  261.925497] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  262.338875] ntfs3: sda: It is recommened to use chkdsk.
[  262.344036] ntfs3: sda: volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set!
[  344.181969] ntfs3: sda: It is recommened to use chkdsk.
[  344.189408] ntfs3: sda: volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set!
[  360.708543] sda: detected capacity change from 30433280 to 0
[  363.111567] usb 7-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  667.137402] usb 7-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  667.171914] usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0918, bcdDevice= 3.10
[  667.171932] usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  667.171939] usb 7-2: Product: Disk 3.0
[  667.171946] usb 7-2: Manufacturer: USB
[  667.171951] usb 7-2: SerialNumber: 4357078231863886
[  667.172793] usb-storage 7-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  667.173288] scsi host0: usb-storage 7-2:1.0
[  668.198980] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB      Disk 3.0         0009 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  668.199767] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  668.200441] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 30433280 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.5 GiB)
[  668.200840] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  668.200848] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[  668.201213] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  668.205473]  sda:
[  668.205584] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  668.587852] ntfs3: sda: It is recommened to use chkdsk.
[  668.594547] ntfs3: sda: volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set!
```

Here is the end of the output of fdisk :

```
$ sudo fdisk -l 
Disque /dev/sda : 14,51 GiB, 15581839360 octets,
30433280 secteurs Disk model: Disk 3.0         Unités : secteur de 1 ×
512 = 512 octets Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets /
512 octets taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets /
512 octets Type d'étiquette de disque : dos Identifiant de disque :
0x00000000
```

Also, I cannot access to my windows partition from ubuntu (I use a dual boot on my laptop) :

```
Error mounting /dev/nvme0n1p3 at /media/username/Windows: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

What could be the issue here ?

Comment: The filesystem on it seems to be corrupt and needs checking/fixing (*with an NTFS aware tool*): `ntfs3: sda: volume is dirty ...` "probably" because it was used on a Windows machine last time.

Comment: I'm not really sure because I use this USB key all the time on a windows machine and a ubuntu machine and I never had some issues… this happens just after updating to 23.10. But let's consider you're right that I need to check/fix the usb key, how can I do it ?

Comment: See for example: [How to correctly fix a "dirty" NTFS partition without using chkdsk](https://askubuntu.com/q/112150)

Comment: The main issue is that /dev/sda1 does not exist : `Failed to access '/dev/sda1': No such file or directory`

Comment: Might be connected: https://askubuntu.com/q/1130564/778232

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem after upgrading to 23.10 (just finished today actually).

I fixed it by using "Repair Filesystem..." option in Disks apps.

However there are warning regarding data loss so please be aware of that and do it with your own risk.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after upgrading ubuntu to 23.10 all of usb disks stop working. I confirm that repairing filesystem in Disk app solve the problem.