# Disk mount error after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: upgrade, mount, 23.10

I have a computer with a 1TB internal drive which has always had Windows 10 running on it. Part of the disk is split into the C: and D: drives used by Windows. These have the names of Windows and LENOVO respectively.
For a couple of years now I have also had Ubuntu dual booting on it, and have had no issues accessing the "C" and "D" drives from Ubuntu.
Having recently upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10, I can't access the "D" drive any more, but "C" access is fine.
When I try to mount "D" I get an error
" Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/chris/LENOVO: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error"

Using Disks, I've checked the mount options for C and D and both are identical ( nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show ), and both use NTFS.

When I boot into Windows I can access both drives fine.
USB drives work fine under the new Ubuntu version.

Any ideas ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489733/23-10-cannot-mount-usb-key This sounds similar. Have you tried running a `chkdsk /F /R` in Windows on the drive?

Comment: Hello moo, thanks for the suggestion, indeed the CHKDSK /F /R did work, even though it found no issues with the D: drive. Very odd, but thanks, I can now access the D: drive from withing Ubuntu as before.

Comment: SHall I post that as an answer?

Comment: Hello moo,Yes, please do post that as the answer.

Comment: already done - see below

Answer (score 1):

The Linux NTFS driver can be more particular about a clean error-free drive than the native Windows driver. To check the drive for errors and attempt to correct any that have been found, it's best to use the native Windows `chkdsk` utility.

Important command line switches for `chkdsk`:

```
/F
Fixes errors on the disk

/R
Locates bad dectors and recovers readable information
```

From within Windows, try:

```
chkdsk /F /R driveletter:
```

If you don't have a native dual-boot Windows system, you can do this from within a virtualised copy of Windows if you [set up your disk for raw access](https://ahelpme.com/software/virtualbox/add-a-raw-disk-to-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine/)