# Problem with mounting USB drive

Tags: usb, mount, ntfs

I have occurred a problem with mounting USB drive. About a week ago there was no problem with it. Error as in pic. When I mount it manually through terminal it works fine, but I have to do it every time and every time it is changing its name f.e. `sda1`/`sdb1` etc.

Error showing during clicking USB-HDD icon:

[image: Error]

Comment: Is it an NTFS file system? In that case the best option is to use a Microsoft tool to repair the file system. In Windows use either a graphical tool or the command line tool `chkdsk X: /f` where X is the drive letter used by Windows. See [this link](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/run-chkdsk-to-check-repair-drive.html) for more details.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492066/disk-mount-error-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-23-10?noredirect=1#comment2617898_1492066